# Он был самым изобретательным физиком из всех, которых я когда-либо встречал

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, будьте добры, можно ли сказать: "Он был самым изобретательным физиком из всех, которых я когда-либо встречал".

Answer (score 1):

Когда говорят "всех", используют "кого": "из всех, кого я встречал". "Которых" лучше звучит в выражении "из тех, которых я встречал". Собственно, слово "всех" само по себе неудачно. Надо ли объяснять почему? Как минимум, рассказчик встречал не всех, а ограниченное количество, для чего есть более точные слова. Рекомендую заменить "всех" на "тех", и тогда всё будет благозвучно и грамотно.

Что же касается выражения, то оно коряво. В хорошем тексте ему места нет. Но если это прямая речь какого-то малограмотного персонажа, то в этом качестве такая фраза имеет право на жизнь. Но только в нём.

Ещё добавлю, что допустимо написание "из всех тех, которых я встречал", но пользы от него нет. Это избыточное выражение. С точки зрения языка оно не уродливо, но зачем это "всех" вообще нужно?

И ещё: почти всегда можно заменить "который" на причастный оборот: "из всех встреченных мной". Не все приветствуют страдательные причастия и вообще такие конструкции, но если Вы не из категории этих писак по методичкам, то можете тоже взять на вооружение. Тогда "всех" останется.

Comment: Если менять "всех" на "тех", то лучше убрать "когда-либо" - оно дополняет пафосное слово "всех". "Из всех, встреченных мной" - это ужас. Надо так: *из всех повстречавшихся мне*.

Comment: Горький, не любивший "вшей" в словах, поспорил бы. Плюс, кажется, запятую Вы забыли, когда написали, как надо.

Comment: Alex_ander тоже заметил связь между "всех" и "когда-либо". Перед "повстречавшихся" запятая не нужна. Но и поставить её можно. Там сложное правило.

Answer (score 1):

Да, так сказать **можно** (не будем выяснять, можно ли это предложение стилистически улучшить или украсить лаконичностью формулировок).

Если рассматривать *изолированно* некоторые словосочетания, они могут показаться "нестандартными": "*все, которые*" можно мысленно противопоставить выражению "*все, кто*", - отсюда возникает пожелание заменить его на "*те, которые*" или "*все, кто*" (в соответствующем падеже). Однако предложение построено не из таких "кубиков". "Все" относится здесь не к неопределённой группе людей,  а к названной (все *физики, которые*), просто во избежание повторения опущено второе слово "физики", что вполне естественно:

> Он был самым изобретательным физиком из всех *[физиков]*, которых я
>   когда-либо встречал.

Может показаться избыточным "когда-либо", но это слово выполняет функцию усиления, делая более категоричным утверждение о "всех" встречавшихся (ср. "*всех без исключения*"). Так что с предложением, на мой взгляд, всё в порядке.

Comment: А какая же разница между "всех, кого" и "всех, которых"? Свою точку зрения расписал в своём ответе. Интересно, как вы считаете.

Comment: Могу сам ответить. Был раньше похожий вопрос. Получается, что "всех, кого" - акцент на объекте, а "всех, которых" - акцент на свойствах объекта. Рассматривать свойства большого количества здесь нецелесообразно - поэтому "которых" звучит хуже.

Answer (score 0):

"*Всех*" на "*тех*" менять не нужно. Это конкретное слово, а не общее:
*из тех, которые занимаются квантовой механикой;

из тех, у которых большой опыт в данной области физики*.

Здесь же смысл - в общем: из всех повстречавшихся в общем за всё время.

"*Которых*" лучше заменить на "*кого*".
Но среди "всех, которых" встречается в книгах - с конкретными по смыслу глаголами:
*среди всех, которых он обучал;

среди всех, которых он видел;

среди всех, которых когда-либо приходилось слышать*.

Интересно то, что "*всех, которых встречал*" возможно по отношению к конкретному действию:
*Среди всех, которых я когда-либо встречал на вокзале.*

Но здесь проблема в другом. Предлог "*из*" - конкретный (сочетается с конкретным местоимением "*тех*"), а слово "*всех*" - нет. Вот оно и не звучит. Нужно заменить на другой предлог:
*Он был самым изобретательным физиком **среди** всех, кого я когда-либо встречал.*

Фразы "*среди всех, кого знал*"/"*среди всех, кого встречал*" довольно распространены. Полно примеров в книгах: [https://www.google.com/search?q="среди+всех,+кого"&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUA875UA875&source=lnms&tbm=bks](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85,%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%22&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUA875UA875&source=lnms&tbm=bks)

Ещё можно переставить слово:
*Он был самым изобретательным среди всех физиков, которых я когда-либо встречал.*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100986/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd--------).

Comment: А с чего Вы взяли, что в данном случае "общее" слово, а не "конкретное"? "Которые занимаются квантовой механикой" — такая же конкретизация, как и "которых встречал я". Нет разницы. Это уже субъективная оценка, но она никак не может выступать в качестве безусловного критерия для выбора слова в отличие от внимания к их сочетаемости.

Comment: Разница есть - разная степень конкретизации. *Которых я вообще только встречал.* Но не *Которые вообще только занимаются квантовой механикой.* Именно "квантовая механика" выступает частным. *Которых встречал на прошлой неделе* - вот так конкретизировано.

Comment: "На неделе", или "в жизни", или "в течение всех своих воплощений" — всё это частные, причём последний вариант будет даже шире, чем тот, который, скорее всего подразумевается контекстом предложения из вопроса. Но, если отталкиваться от Ваших утверждений, это "частное "будет уже "общего", хотя этот общий — сокращённый вариант того же частного: "которых я встречал в жизни", ну, или "вообще в жизни" или "вообще когда-либо в жизни только встречал". Как по мне, "тех" или "всех", выбор всегда за автором. Нет правила, способного ограничить выбор между этими словами.

Comment: Ну вы и закрутили)  "В течение всех своих воплощений" — гораздо более общее, здесь частным и не пахнет. Частность зависит от смысла, а не от количества слов. Да не звучит здесь "тех". Никто не ограничивает, но всегда что-то лучше, а что-то хуже. *Которых встречал в принципе* — общее. *Которые занимаются в принципе* — здесь так не получается. По аналогии с общей оценкой за знание русского - и с оценкой за какую-то тему. И теперь центральный пример, который отражает мою "концепцию": *Компьютеры способны помочь тем/всем, кто живёт на нашей планете.*

Comment: А теперь сама суть. *Дать конкретно [именно] тем, кто.* Но не *Дать конкретно всем, кто.* *Абсолютно всем [в общем], кто*. Но не *Абсолютно тем [в общем], кто*.